# reading multiple jpg images from one file

Tags: c++, c, jpeg

I have a file that contains multiple jpg images. I want to read them one by one into buffers to decode them seperately. I dont know if there is any different information saved in the file other than the image headers and the image data.

A jpg image starts with the SOI byte and ends with the EOI byte. Can I assume that these bytes only appear at the start and the end of an image?
Then I would try to read unsigned char pieces into a buffer and only check if I found SOI or EOI.

Would that work?
(Still in the planning phase, therefore no code yet...Will be in c or c++ though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markers are actually two octets, 0xFF plus the actual marker code.  SOI is 0xFF,0xD8 and EOI is 0xFF,0xD9.  Additionally, the standard says when you're encoding image data, if you encode a 0xFF octet (i.e. it's not a marker) then you need to follow it with a 0x00 so that decoders/scanners don't think it's a marker (this is called byte stuffing).  Anyway, given this, you should be fine scanning for SOI and EOI markers.

**Edit:** You may find images that have embedded thumbnails... in which case you might need to keep count of the markers... e.g. 0xFF,0xD8,...0xFF,0xD8,...0xFF,D9...0xFF,D9 would be a single image with an embedded thumbnail.

Comment: Do you by any chance know, if I can just check if(c== 0xFF) if c is an unsigned char?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.